# ajax is not working while sending string in return value

Tags: java, ajax, spring, model-view-controller, return

My ajax call is

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    headers : {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content")
    },
    url : url,
    contentType : "application/json",
    data : JSON.stringify(subdata),
    success : function(data) {
        alert("Added sussefull");
        alert(data);
        alert(data.message);
    },
    error : function() {
        alert("in error");
    }
});
```

my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addcourse",method =RequestMethod.POST,produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody String addCourse(@RequestBody Subject subject) 
{       
    String message = subjectService.addSub(subject);
    return message;
}
```

Ajax call is not working if I am sending string value, if I changed string to void its working.

Comment: *not working if I am sending string value , if I changed string to void its working* Could you elaborate more ? Share what error are you getting

Comment: Where is your `subdata` ? and are you getting the alert `Added sussefull` or `in error` ?